# JQuery-Selector $(this).next("input[name='foo']") doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to react with `.change()` on a value change. I that case, an other (hidden) field must be updated.

```
<input type="text" name="n1"><br>
<input type="text" name="n2"><br>
<input type="text" name="n3"><br>    
<input type="hidden" name="h1"><br>
<script>
$("input[type='text']").change( function() {

 try {
     $temp = $(this).next("input[type='hidden']");
 } catch (e) { // just for testing
     alert("not found "+e);
} 
 try {    
     $temp = $(this).next("input[name='h1']");
} catch (e) { { // just for testing
     alert("not found "+e);
}     
 $temp.val("hidden");
 alert("Temp is a "+$temp);
    alert("Temp has following value:"+$temp.val());

})
</script>
```

Demo for testing at: http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/1209/

This statement

```
$temp = $(this).next("input[type='hidden']");
```

> results in a "**not defined**", or better: $temp is an $object[] and
>   not (as aspected) $object[*input* name='h1']

Where is the problem?

Comment: What should `} catch (e if e instanceof ReferenceError) {` be? Throws a syntax error...

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Yeah I was a bit confused by this as well, it's also not in the ECMAScript spec, here is more on it -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: and with a valid selector syntax it will never throw, so what's the point.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** then you will find the element you are looking for.

```
$(this).nextAll("input[type='hidden']");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/1212/)

Answer (score 0):

Use nextAll(), and be carefull on your catch blocks (those in the fiddle ;)).

I would not use two try/catch block, because even if $temp is filled in the first block, it will be overrided by the second.

Note that change event will be fired only when input loses focus.

I updated your fiddle:

```
$temp = $(this).nextAll("input[type='hidden']");
if($temp.length <= 0) $temp = $(this).nextAll("input[name='h1']");
```

**[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/22C2n/1214/)**